# Page goes blank when I try to use a certain component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mern

I pulled code from git repo and added two new file components `Men.js` and `Card.js` to it. When I try to route to components `Men.js` or `Card.js` the page goes blank but all other existing components in the folder gets rendered. No error is displayed.

Even without routing the `Men` and `Card` does not get displayed when I use them in `App.js`

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import './style.css'
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Routes, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./Home";
import Usersignin from "./Usersignin";
import Usersignup from "./Usersignup";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Card from "./Card";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Men from "./Men";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Nav/>
       <Routes> 

        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/signin' element={<Usersignin/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/signup' element={<Usersignup/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/women' element={<Card/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/men' element={<Men/>}/>

      </Routes> 

      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Nav.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <div class="container-fluid" id="nav-container">
      <nav className="container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-lg Navbar shadow px-2">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
            E-commerce
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  to="#"
                  id="navbarDropdown"
                  role="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                >
                  All Products
                </a>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li>
                    {/* <a className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                      1st Product
                    </a> */}
                    <Link className="dropdown-item" aria-current="page" to="/men">Men</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    {/* <a className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                    2nd Product
                    </a> */}
                    <Link className="dropdown-item" aria-current="page" to="/women">Women</Link>
                  </li>
                  {/* <li>
                    <hr className="dropdown-divider" />
                  </li> */}
                  <li>
                    {/* <a className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                    3rd Product
                    </a> */}
                    <Link className="dropdown-item" aria-current="page" to="/">Kids</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="#">
                  Order Form
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link">Gallery</a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to='/signin'>Sign In</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Men.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card'

export default function Men() {
  return (
    <>
        <Card/>
        <Card/>
        <Card/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Card() {
  return (
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
  )
}
```

All other components like `Usersignin,Usersignup,Home` all render, they are from the existing git repo that I pulled while `Men and Card` components I have added. I m not getting why this happens please help me.

Comment: Could You provide a link to the repo please and present App.js?

Comment: https://github.com/naikmohit13/Ecommerce_Sample

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword in javascript and JSX is an extension of javascript. That's the principal reason why React uses `className` instead of `class`.

Comment: The repo you linked seems to render without issue, but also appears to be missing the components you say you have an issue working with. Please provide all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cloned Your repo and add missing components (`Men.js` and `Card.js`)  You have problem with `Card.js` component.

You need to change:

1. `class` to `className`
2. `style="width: 18rem;"` to `style={{ width: "18rem" }}`

(https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Like that and it works like a charm ! ;-) But You have still a lot warnings and a lot to do ;-)

```
import React from "react";

export default function Card() {
  return (
    <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
      <img src="..." className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p className="card-text">
          Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
          bulk of the card's content.
        </p>
        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
          Go somewhere
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`http://localhost:3000/men` Output :

[image]

`http://localhost:3000/women` Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution MarioG8 just had one doubt.....Do I have to commit the files that I have added to see changes in the local machine too?

Comment: The men and card components were not in the repo, I cloned the repo and added these two components by myself but I am unable to see chnages even in my local machine...What might br the reason?

Comment: @MohitNaik You can, but you don't have to, with my solution you should see above output ;-) Good Luck

Comment: @MohitNaik You're welcome ! Glad I Could help You ! ;-)  Now You can mark my answer as solved your problem :-) !